# Badges Copy Editor and Archaeologist

Tags: support, badges, edits

I occasionally clean Swing related questions (from 01/jan/2011) on SO, and I want to get the Archaeologist Badge for that.

My question is if edits (to the posts that were inactive for 6 months and more) are recorded separately for the Copy Editor badge and the Archaeologist badge, or do I have to wait a few  months for Copy Editor, then start to clean up the Swing posts

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edits are not stuffed into slots assigned to a particular badge; badges are assigned based on queries that look at all relevant actions.

In other words, editing a 6-month-inactive post will count towards Archaeologist as well as count toward Copy Editor.

Comment: @matthew how do you know what is an inactive for 6 month?

Comment: @BookOfZeus Look at the timestamp on the post.

Answer (score 25):

Badges exist to encourage behaviors that make the site/network/Internet a better place. Gold ones, especially, are nice to have, but you probably shouldn't wait to make the Internet better just to earn one.

But yes, edits of old posts will double-count.