# Isn't [sscce] a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta-tags

There are some questions that are being retagged with [sscce](/questions/tagged/sscce) because they contain a " Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example". But I find that almost [all programming questions should contain a short example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) to describe the problem.

I don't find the [sscce](/questions/tagged/sscce) tag to [provide anything to the question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), so why are they used? Isn't the [sscce](/questions/tagged/sscce) tag a good example of a "meta tag" that should be removed?

Comment: It certainly looks like tag abuse. It looks like [mKorbel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) is going for a [Taxonomist](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge.

Comment: @ChrisF: Or [Andrew](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) that started(?) to use the tag and has a good article [The SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). It's a good document, but I don't find it helpful to tag questions with it.

Comment: Ah - I just saw that mKorbel had edited most (if not all of the questions with the tag just to add the tag.

Comment: @ChrisF could you please to inform me about number of question where I added tag, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107119/badges-copy-editor-and-archaeologist

Comment: @mKorbel - I didn't write down the numbers. It was just when I checked the questions that were tagged with [sscce] I saw your name as the last editor on most of them and the ones I checked just had an edit to add the tag. I didn't have time to go through them all.

Comment: @ChrisF that's irrelevant number, .... I was ensure that you are talking about mKorbel && Tags, :-) thanks, my +1 for deepest analyze

Comment: @mKorbel: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1026/editor-strunk-white-copy-editor) is interesting if you want to see your progress to Copy Editor tag.

Comment: @Jonas thanks I saw this query (or similair), I checked that before I asked my question on Meta, CopyEditor doesn't interesting me somehow, Archaeologist too much, and why not CopyEditor because (I daily edited 10-20 post on SO) by default only adds the tags, In case that question is good, better or great only then I edit body, :-) I leave these threads for CopyEditors sharks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm familiar with the "Short, Self Contained, (Correct) Compilable Example" concept, but I wouldn't have guessed what the tag meant from the context of most of those posts.  It also is a meta tag as you pointed out, so that's two reasons to get rid of it.  I removed it from all of the posts on SO and left a comment for the guy who was adding it asking him to stop.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288335/button-logic-ignored-why

Comment: @mKorbel  I did not participate in that linked thread & I had not been notified of your comments.  I only became aware of them now because I have a Google alert for 'sscce', and it listed *this* thread.  ;)

Answer (score 11):

Having created the SSCCE tag, as well as having applied it to a number of posts, I now have to say it seems silly to have done either.

My apologies.

Comment: I appreciate all your Swing activity and your SSCCE guidelines are good. I hope you don't take this personally it was just about the tag. Your contribution on StackOverflow is valuable.

Comment: I'm not offended by your question, in fact, I gave it a +1 for clarifying/confirming my suspicion that the tag was a bad idea.  I'm really more interested in gaining 'tags that work' than 'tags that stroke my own ego' ( in case you did not realize - I started/edit the SSCCE document as well ;).

Answer (score 2):

1) yes that very silly

- as I know then >90% Tag edits for Swing question were edited by my person, then no suprise, no miracle, whatever ... nothing special in the last 4moths, then are everywhere with my name
- true is that I never checking (waiting for popup window) if Tag exists or not
- cruel reality, probably I created a few new tags but with same un-happy end as for example [How to bold a whole row of data in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4597231/714968). But any reason for delete was adviced only by @Bill the Lizard. Then pretty could be possible that I created new tag daily, maybe againg daily was deleted by some from TagCleaner, and so on ...
- not remember that someone notify or abuse any of my edit, nor that were re-taged,
- and another more than silly stories, that I can't on never to want to solve somehow

2) then there must exist another Swing rellated Tag, where is my edit only (I checked that for fun) leading with windowlistener (>20 rellated),

3) and for potential TagCleaner is there lots of works ([in this context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107119/badges-copy-editor-and-archaeologist))

4) please could someone tell me if I made something wrong, and I think that is silly that one more rusty point is real payment for that, or am I wrong and those points are more than I think ...

Comment: @Andrew Thompson why apologized by your person, please see my post here

Comment: If you get 200k reps you can redeem a painting of unicorns set to beautiful rainbows. Only works if your name is Jon Skeet though (or so I've heard)

Comment: mKorbel, you haven't done anything wrong. This is just about the `[sscce]`-tag since it didn't describe the content of the question. Don't take this personally. You can continue with re-tagging if it improves the question and the tags describe the content. But it's rarely that we have to use new tags. New tags should be created only if they are common enough that people may use them for searching posts.

Comment: Andrew will not see your comment, you need to write the comment to his answer, otherwise he is not notified of your comment.

Comment: @Yi Jiang's 独角兽 yes no doubt these are the rules for the herd, not my :-)

Comment: @Jonas anything about this tag is as put the salt into open wounds, especially for Andrew, please remove this notify

Comment: @mKorbel: Come on, I appreciate all your Swing and re-tagging activity. Your contribution is valuable. This was just about the sscce-tag that wasn't useful. It's good that you inform about SSCCE when needed, but it's not useful as a tag.

Comment: *">90% Tag edits for Swing question were edited by my person"* Yes, I've been noticing with bemusement when a bunch of posts from February jump into my feed reader.  ..Are we up to March yet?  ;)  Good call on editing those atrocious posts to make them more readable, but I have to say I agree with Jonas' basic point about the SSCCE tag.  It does not qualify as a tag in the way they are used on SO.  And since I'm offering apologies, I'll extend an apology to you specifically, since I know how much effort you put in (wasted) on adding the SSCCE tag to posts.

Comment: `Are we up to March yet? ;)`, something wrong happands, where you lost January:-), long time up 18/Feb/2011, last 2weeks I have no free time for reading these post, but in this (historical posts) case I only tagged posts without rellevant Swing Tag, leave and don't opening the posts that contains Swing tag, not reason for that, nor to reading these posts, add tag(s) or re-tag(s), just initially posts without Swing Tag,