# Do tag edits count for Archaeologist?

Tags: discussion, edit-badges

I know tag-edits do not count towards the 500 edits required for the Copy Editor badge. Do they count to the 100 for the Archaeologist badge? It seems they should because you are making a 6-month-inactive post active again.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that they don't, but I agree that it would make the most sense if they did.

Comment: @shawizdoward Thanks for trying. Don't know why it's so hard to provide an official answer on this.

Comment: The team is busy with bugs and stuff, no big deal.

Answer (score 14):

No they don't count, I edited tags for unknow numbers question (400-500 maybe more) for 1Q/2011, but by default without editing body of Q&A, I leave got this badge see [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107119/badges-copy-editor-and-archaeologist)

Comment: So after 400 tag edits on 6-month-inactive questions you did not get the badge?

Comment: I din't edited body of Q&A (question and answer), only modified tags