# Does tag edit count for Excavator badge?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, badges, edit-badges

Have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186772/187824). User is asking for clarification for why he didn't earn that badge. That user edited (re-tagged) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808464/1369235) which was inactive for more than 6 months. But he didn't earn the badge. Does tag edit count for Excavator badge?

If no, we need to mention it on [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/187824).
If yes, Why didn't that user earn that badge? ([other users who edited after him has already earned the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186772/excavator-badge-not-awarded-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment-573376).)

Comment: He asked 3 hours ago. Some batches run only once a day.

Comment: @juergend - See the last line mentioned in the brackets. :-)

Comment: @juergend - Did you get what I mean? The user who edited [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9287352/revisions) at 09:30:11 [got the badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator?userid=1900251) at 09:53:24. So this badge doesn't run once a day.

Comment: Yes, saw it. Looks like either retagging doesn't count or suggested edits don't count.

Comment: [whoops](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126624/152859)! My bad for leading you to post this while it was asked before. Started  bounty there now, hoping to draw some dev(s) to the shiny rep. ;)

Comment: @juergend - [Suggested edits](http://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/466/revisions) counts for [this badge](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/excavator?userid=540).