# Does inline tag editing affect Illuminator badge?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, badges, edit-and-answer-badges

I've answered a question then edited the tag inline since there was nothing more to edit. Then waited for *long enough* so that I can see an increase in the Illuminator count. It did not increase, then I've edited a dummy text in the question to see the effect. I've got it immediately. [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/96606/18298) was the question. So;

Does inline tag editing affect the  Illuminator badge or not?

Comment: According to the link I suggested above: "*Only body and title edits on the question count, tag-only edits do not.*"

Comment: So, tag edits are not a good edit. What an interesting decision

Comment: See also: [What's the reasoning for why tag edits don't count for "question edit badges"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281785/323179)